# How to redirect users to a secure domain

Tags: javascript, ssl

I obtained an SSL certificate for my website, however the site does not show as secure unless I physically type in https://www.examplesite.com.

If I just type www.examplesite.com my site is not secure.

My question is do I create a redirect of some sort using javascript to automatically take users to the https:// domain, or is this an issue with the certificate itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way with .htaccess file.

Add .htaccess file at root directory with this to automatically redirect http request to https :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If your website is present on OVH :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If your website is present on Gandi (instance Simple Hosting) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Of course you need a valid certificate to use correctly this solution.

Comment: Thankyou! Also, is there a way to ensure that www. shows everytime?